# How to change color for unique RaisedButton?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of string :

> List _choice = ["Europe","Asia","Africa"];

For each value i generate RaisedButton: 
[image]

I have an other variable :

> String answer = "Europe";

My goal: 
if the user clicks on any Raisedbutton, change the color to green for the one where Text value equals the value of answer. For other where Text value isn't equals the value of answer, change color to red.

The problem with my code is all RaisedButton change to red or green.

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<String> _choice = <String>["Europe","Asia","Africa"];
    String answer = "Europe";
    int NumberChoice = _choice.length;

    //RaisedButtons
                        for (var i = 0; i < NumberChoice; i++)
                          new RaisedButton(
                            color: _colorButton,
                            child: new Text(
                              _choice[i],
                              style: new TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.white),
                            ),
                            onPressed: () {
                              setState(() {
                                if (_choice[i] == answer) {
                                  print("--------------- Corect ----------------");
                                  _colorButton = Colors.greenAccent;
                                  scoreResult = 1;
                                } else {
                                  print("--------------- False ------------------------");
                                  _colorButton = Colors.redAccent;
                                  scoreResult = 0;
                                }
                              });
                            },
                          ),
```

Comment: you gave `_colorButton` to all of the `RaisedButton`, that's why..., you should give different color based on index.

Comment: Thx, is-it possible to give a unique id for each RaisedButton like RaisedButton_1, RaisedButton_2, .... ?

Comment: I have given the answer to your problem @ThibautFAURE. Let me know if that works out for you. Thanks

Comment: Hey @ThibautFAURE, I have found the solution, **please find it below for the edited answer**. It will work now. Please give it a thumbs up and mark it as correct. Will be waiting to get your response. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved your case finally. It required a lot of efforts, but finally, we are there.

What I have done is, I have **rebuilt the widget on the press of button and changed the color in the color key itself of the RaisedButton()**

I know it will sound a little bit complex but after looking into the solution you will get it.

Before moving to the solution, here is the demonstration. The buttons were pink by default, as soon as I hit on any button, the result will show up, wrong answers = red and right = green

[image: Demo of the result]

```
class RadioButtonPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  RadioButtonPageState createState() => RadioButtonPageState();

}

class RadioButtonPageState extends State<RadioButtonPage> {

  List<String> _choice = ["Europe","Asia","Africa"];
  String answer = "Europe";
  var score;

  //this bool does the real magic since you want the result to be seen on the press of the button, so here you go, this keeps track of the pressed button whether it is pressed once or not
  bool isPressedOnce = false;

  List<Widget> getButtons(){
    List<Widget> _listWidget = [];
     for(int i=0; i< _choice.length; i++){
      _listWidget.add(
        RaisedButton(
           //Everytime it builds up, it will work according to this situation, hence works
          color: isPressedOnce ? (_choice[i] == answer ? Colors.greenAccent : Colors.red) : Colors.pink,
          child: Text(_choice[i]),
          onPressed: (){
            //Changes the state of bool to true, since any button is pressed
            setState(() {
              this.isPressedOnce = true;
              if(_choice[i] == this.answer) score = 1;
              else score = 0;
            });

            //Rebuilding the widget again, and now with the current condition I have put on that color key,  it will finally work as per the requirements
            this.getButtons();
          }
        )
      );
    }

    return _listWidget;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
     appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Welcome'),
     ),
     body: Center(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: this.getButtons()
       )
     )
   );
  }
}
```

Comment: I have already use the setState(), and for achieving the same, we have to do something similar to this @Eugene. Let me know if you have some other solution. I would be grateful to learn from you. Thanks. But do not downvote it, it is a workaround for him since nobody helped him on this answer.